# How do I get this appearance in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, themes, customization

Can you help me to change window's appearance in Ubuntu 16.04 to be like this image?

[image]

Comment: That looks like Mac OS to me: http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html

Comment: Yes I've installed MacBuntu Theme but it doesn't have this effect around the buttons

Comment: @A.Henteti I wrote an answer. Please check if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In past, many of the Ubuntu themes had those Mac-Like looks. It's hard to say the exact theme just by looking at the image. However, I have one theme that has same visual looks. The name of the theme is `mac-ithemes-v3` and is provided by old noobslab themes PPA. The problem is this theme is for Ubuntu 14.04 and hasn't been updated for later releases.

However, if you must own this theme, you can grab the deb package for Trusty and install it using `dpkg -i`.

```
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes/+files/mac-ithemes-v3_3.12-c~trusty~NoobsLab.com_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mac-ithemes-v3_3.12-c~trusty~NoobsLab.com_all.deb
```

You should now be able to use this theme (with some problem) in Xenial Xerus. This package has multiple themes included. You'd select `Mbuntu-mb` for that look.

Here is a screenshot of same CCSM program using the theme.

[image: mac theme screenshot of ccsm]

Comment: @A.Henteti Thanks to you too! Hope it will work for you :)