# Is there a old-school retro style Ubuntu theme or DE?

Tags: themes, desktop-environments

just wonder if there is such theme or DE which seems like retro-style.
Such as a mono-tone GUI. Actually, an old Mac style would be best.

Comment: Any old Mac style?

Comment: Like this? http://askubuntu.com/q/823519/158442

Comment: Visit http://www.ubuntuthemes.org/